# Why is my discord bot repeating the on_ready function endlessly

Tags: python, postgresql, discord.py

I'm writing a bot for discord and my on_ready function is repeating endlessly after I rewrote it with PostgreSQL. Here is my code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    """The on_ready function is executed when the bot starts and creates the users table in the database, also adds names, id, the number of xp and the server of all participants that are not in the database to the database.
    """
    DiscordComponents(bot)
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        name VARCHAR(255), 
        id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
        xp INT
    );""")
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if member.id not in bots:
                try:
                    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{}', {}, {});""".format(member, member.id, 0))
                except:
                    continue
    connect.commit()
    print("Bot connected!")
```

Why is this happening and how to correct it and why this function don't add data in the data base?

Comment: did you read the documentation? `This function is not guaranteed to be the first event called. Likewise, this function is not guaranteed to only be called once. This library implements reconnection logic and thus will end up calling this event whenever a RESUME request fails.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on_ready` event can be called many times because a bot can reconnect to Discord. So, I would recommend you write something like this:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@tasks.loop(count=1)
async def wait_until_ready():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    # update your database and do whatever here

wait_until_ready.start()
bot.run('token')
```

Then you would update database only once after first `on_ready` event.